# how to create a choropleth map with mapbox gl js

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I want to create a choropleth map using mapbox gl js.
is there a way to  iterate through features and their properties ?
I need a way similar to

```
feature.properties
```

Answer (score 3):

Mapbox GL 0.19 [adds](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/releases/tag/v0.19.0) a more natural way to create choropleths: [data-driven styling](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/data-driven-styling/).

Following [their example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/updating-choropleth/), you can define `stops` for the `fill-color` tied to a particular property. MapboxGL will interpolate between the values.

```js
map.addLayer({
    'source': 'dataset',
    'type': 'fill',
    'paint': {
        'fill-color': {
            property: 'population',
            stops: [
                [0, 'white'],
                [100, 'red']
            ]
        },
        'fill-opacity': 0.75
    }
})
```